# Finite time singularity without blowing up to infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in an example of the following:

An initial value problem of the form:

$$ x'(t) = f(x(t),t) \qquad x(0) = x_0 $$

I want it to have the following property:

- $f(x,t)$ Lipchitz continuous on  $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$
- the maximal solution to the initial value problem is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$
- the maximal solution to the initial value problem is bounded on its domain.

Comment: Impossible. It’s a theorem that every solution to an ODE which isn’t defined after a certain time must never return to any compact set from a certain point. The proof is a bit technical – basically you just show that the existence time of a solution is bounded below for an initial point in said compact.

Comment: Can you name the theorem or give a reference for it?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t. I remember that because it was a homework question I had to solve a few eternities ago. But the argument is very simple: write the proof for the existence theorem and keep the constants explicit. You can thus show that for any compact $K$, there is a time $\tau > 0$ such that any initial value in $K$ has an existence time $\geq \tau$. In particular, if the solution isn’t defined after the time $t$, then it can’t be in $K$ at any time greater than $t-\tau$.

Comment: Ah I see. So this is because existence time is lower semi-continuous as a function of initial value. Very nice, thanks!

Comment: @JoelVillatoro   In the language of manifolds, it's called the Escape Lemma. I don't know how it is called otherwise, but [here](http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec5.pdf) is a proof.

Comment: If conversely, the ODE has at least one point where is Non-Lipschitz, it is possible to have an scenario where solutions of finite duration are possible (but uniqueness is lost). For autonomous 1st and 2nd order ODEs you could see the papers "Finite Time Controllers" and "Finite Time differential equations" by V. T. Haimo (1985). As example, $x'=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|},\,\,x(0)=1$ could stand the solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{t}{2}+|1-\frac{t}{2}|\right)^2$